# Mongodb Shrading gives config server not synched error?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have created three instance of mongodb on localhost with different port like

```
mongod.exe --configsvr --dbpath C:\MongoDB2.6\mongodb\data --port 2021

mongod.exe --configsvr --dbpath D:\mongodb\data --port 2022

mongod.exe --configsvr --dbpath E:\mongodb\data --port 2023
```

These 3 are getting instantiated successfully.
Now I am using mongos command for clustring for these three instance and my command is like this

```
mongos.exe --configdb 127.0.0.1:2021,127.0.0.1:2022,127.0.0.1:2023
```

BUt it gives me the error which is like this

```
C:\MongoDB2.6\bin>mongos.exe --configdb 127.0.0.1:2021,127.0.0.1:2022,127.0.0.1:2023 --port 2025
2015-02-26T15:51:22.451+0530 [mongosMain] MongoS version 2.6.7 starting: pid=12256 port=2025 64-bit host=triconnode112 (--help for usage)
2015-02-26T15:51:22.451+0530 [mongosMain] db version v2.6.7
2015-02-26T15:51:22.451+0530 [mongosMain] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
2015-02-26T15:51:22.451+0530 [mongosMain] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOO
ST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-02-26T15:51:22.451+0530 [mongosMain] allocator: system
2015-02-26T15:51:22.466+0530 [mongosMain] options: { net: { port: 2025 }, sharding: { configDB: "127.0.0.1:2021,127.0.0.1:2022,127.0.0.1:2023" } }
2015-02-26T15:51:22.482+0530 [mongosMain] warning: config servers 127.0.0.1:2021 and 127.0.0.1:2022 differ
2015-02-26T15:51:22.482+0530 [mongosMain] warning: config servers 127.0.0.1:2021 and 127.0.0.1:2022 differ
2015-02-26T15:51:22.482+0530 [mongosMain] warning: config servers 127.0.0.1:2021 and 127.0.0.1:2022 differ
2015-02-26T15:51:22.498+0530 [mongosMain] warning: config servers 127.0.0.1:2021 and 127.0.0.1:2022 differ
2015-02-26T15:51:22.498+0530 [mongosMain] ERROR: could not verify that config servers are in sync :: caused by :: config servers 127.0.0.1:2021 and 127.0.0.1:20
22 differ: { chunks: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", shards: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", version: "9c051057927f3ebf9b0ee68b4b0ff78d" } vs { chunks:
"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", shards: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", version: "4c0907d023ca1c1216c89d83fcb6a841" }
2015-02-26T15:51:22.498+0530 [mongosMain] configServer connection startup check failed
```

I am not getting where i am doing mistake. In this full example actually i am trying to implement sharding for the mongodb.

Now I am able to solve this problema nd tried to execute the shard command which is

```
 sh.addShard("127.0.0.1:2021,127.0.0.1:2022,127.0.0.1:2023")
```

Now it gives me the error

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "can't use sync cluster as a shard.  for replica set, have to use <setname>/<server1>,<server2>,..."
}
```

I have no idea why this error is coming.

Comment: You're trying to add the three config servers as a shard - this doesn't make sense. The config servers manage the cluster metadata. You should be making a standalone mongod or replica set to be a shard. Please look over the [sharding intro](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/) and [tutorial on setting up sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).

Comment: I am using the same link which you have provided me to implement the sharding.